# Are 'local[n]' pyspark applications effected by the GIL?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, gil

Generally python doesn't work well with multi threading because of the Global Interpreter Lock.

Does this affect also pyspark applications running in multi threaded local mode (local[n])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallelization in pyspark is achieved by daemon.py calling `os.fork()` to create multiple worker processes, so there won't be GIL issues.